# Compiling MuPDF

Tags: android, mupdf

I'm trying to compiling the latest release (cloned git repo today) of MuPDF library.

1. Check out a copy of the mupdf source from git:

   git clone git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git
2. Check out the third party library submodules:

   git submodule update --init
3. Populate the generated directory with the necessary files:

   make generate

But, when I enter the last command, I got these errors:

```
LINK build/debug/cmapdump
build/debug/cmapdump.o: In function `fz_free_context':
/home/luca/Java/Extra/libraries/mupdf/scripts/../fitz/base_context.c:55: undefined     reference to `fz_drop_colorspace_context'
build/debug/cmapdump.o: In function `fz_new_context':
/home/luca/Java/Extra/libraries/mupdf/scripts/../fitz/base_context.c:142: undefined reference to `fz_new_colorspace_context'
build/debug/cmapdump.o: In function `fz_clone_context_internal':
/home/luca/Java/Extra/libraries/mupdf/scripts/../fitz/base_context.c:186: undefined    reference to `fz_keep_colorspace_context'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/debug/cmapdump] Error 1
```

Seems that the linker cannot resolve the required objects...so I cannot go on.

I wonder if someone else tried to compile (this release) and had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has been fixed, literally in the last few minutes, I suggest you update to the latest source.

Comment: I fixed right now adding: void  fz_drop_colorspace_context(fz_context*ctx) { }

void fz_new_colorspace_context(fz_context *ctx) { }

fz_colorspace_context * fz_keep_colorspace_context(fz_context *ctx) { return NULL; } to cmapdump.c  but I'll checkout the last release..thanks

Comment: @KenS As I enter the command `make generate`, nothing happens. I can't even input anymore, the cursor is just blinking and I'm not sure if its still generating or what.

Comment: I have implement mupdf lib but its take too much time for open pdf, So can you suggest me how to show loader when it load pdf file?